# Criar divs dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, div

Senhores,

Estou trabalhando com tabs em Jquery. Eu tenho uma página chamado incluir_servidor.php aonde faço o insert no banco de quantos servidores eu quiser. Eu preciso que após clicar no botão próximo a quantidade de abas da página seja a mesma da quantidade de registros que foram inseridos na página anterior. Isso eu até consegui fazer com o código abaixo:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php
            do {  
        ?>
            <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>"><?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?></a></li>
        <?php
            } while ($row_menu_servidor = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_servidor));
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($menu_servidor);
                if($rows > 0) {
                    mysql_data_seek($menu_servidor, 0);
                    $row_menu_servidor = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_servidor);
                            }               
        ?>          
    </ul>
```

Meu problema agora é que preciso que o conteúdo dessa DIV ou dessa TAB/ABA também seja dinâmico. Pelo o que estou imaginando, eu preciso declarar que para cada

```
<li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>"><?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?></a></li>` a página inclua uma DIV com o conteúdo `<div id="tabs-ndcingmgm001">
            <div id="id_solic"><div style="position: absolute; margin-left:10px; margin-top:-10px; width:100px; height: 10;"><br/>
                <h4>ID Solicitação<br>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <input name="id_solic" id="id_solic" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['id_solic'];?>" size="5" readonly="readonly">
                    <br><br>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Acredito que eu tenha que fazer o ID dessa DIV conteudo ser dinâmico, de acordo com a quantidade de registros da query passada acima.

Espero ter conseguido explicar com clareza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta para a sua pergunta (se eu entendi) é **SIM**, o id precisa ser dinâmico.

Para cada aba que você quiser ter você deverá, criar uma div com um **id** e apontar esse mesmo **id** no `href` do link dentro da `li` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Primeira Aba</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Segunda Aba</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Terceira Aba</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    bla bla bla 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    bla bla bla 2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    bla bla bla 3
  </div>
</div>
```

mais exemplos no [site da jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: deFreitas, eu entendi isso mas eu estou pegando o href de acordo com a query que executei. Ela pode ter 10 registros como pode ter 2.
 Eu preciso que o ID da tabs seja igual ao colocado no href por variavel.
<a href="#tabs-<?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>"><?php echo $row_menu_servidor['host_servidor']?>